# reading JavaScript object in a file into a Python array

Tags: javascript, python, converters

I have a javascript file that has an object I'd like to be read by Python (Python 3 is just fine).  Something like this:

```js
let variable_i_do_not_want = 'foo'
let function_i_do_not_wnt = function() {

}

// .. etc ..

// --- begin object I want ---
myObject = {
    var1: 'value-1',
    var2: 'value-2',
    fn2: function() {
       "I don't need functions.."
    },
    mySubObject: {
       var3: 'value-3',
       .. etc ..
    }
}
// --- end object I want ---

// .. more stuff I don't want ..
```

I want to convert `myObject` to a python dict object.  Note I don't really need the functions, just keys and values.

I'm fine with (and capable) adding comment markers before/after and isolating the object.  But I think I need a library to convert that string into a Python dict. Is this possible?

Comment: The JavaScript source code could serialize the object to a JSON file which the Python code could then load.

Comment: There's no "javascript source code" in this case, it's vanilla JS with no build.  I'm interested in having one source of truth for the values in this JavaScript file object

Comment: You appear to have shown us a JavaScript source file. What's preventing you writing some additional, simple JS to import or otherwise use that source to dump the object to a JSON file? Or even start with a JSON file and also populate myObject in the JS from that. You're probably going to find JSON a simpler sharing mechanism than trying to parse JavaScript from Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this using python would be a lot of work that can be avoided if you could add a few things directly in your javascript file. (as you told you could modify the js file)

I assume that you have nodejs and npm preinstalled (if not then you can install it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

You need to add these lines of code at the end of the JS file.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const getVals = (obj) => {
  let myData = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (
      !(typeof obj[key] === "function") && // ignore functions
      (!(typeof obj[key] == "object") || Array.isArray(obj[key])) // ignore objects (except arrays)
    ) {
      myData[key] = obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") { // if it's an object, recurse
      myData = {
        ...myData,
        ...getVals(obj[key]),
     };
    }
  }
  return myData;
};

// storing the data into a json file
fs.writeFile(
  "myjsonfile.json",
  JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(getVals(myObject))), //change your variable name here instead of myObject (if needed)
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("complete");
  }
);
```

once you add this you can run the js file by

```
~$ npm init -y
~$ node yourjsfile.js
```

This will make a new file named myjsonfile.json with the data which you can load from python like this

```
import json

with open('myjsonfile.json') as file:
    d=json.loads(file.read()) #your dict
    print(d)
```

;)